# Move to next charAt()

Tags: java, string, args, charat

I'm having a problem in my program that will replace each character in the string entered (specifically from args[x]).

I am able to get the first character in the string but what I don't know how to do is moving to the next character. I tried the "ctr++" below but it will only loop the 1st character of the string.

The outcome is:
String: aei
  Decrypt: ZZZ

What I need is:
String: aei
Decrypt: ZYX

Here's a segment of my code:

```
for( int a = 0; a < len; a++ )
                {
                    args[x].charAt(ctr);
                    switch (letter) 
                        {
                            case 'a': System.out.print("Z"); break;  //1

                            case 'e': System.out.print("Y"); break;  //2

                            case 'i': System.out.print("X"); break;     //3

                            case 'o': System.out.print("W"); break;  //4

                            case 'u': System.out.print("V"); break;  //5 

                            case 'A': System.out.print("z"); break;     //6

                            case 'E': System.out.print("y"); break;     //7

                            .
                            .
                            .
                            .
                        }
                        ctr++;
                    }
```

It would be appreciated if anyone could help.

Comment: Where are you assigning `letter`?

Comment: Can you please specify what is 'len' , 'x' in args[x] and  where does this 'letter' come from ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, your problem is that you never change the value of `letter`. You need to replace `args[x].charAt(ctr)` with `letter = args[x].charAt(ctr)`.

Comment: This did it! I thought that the value would change because letter was in another class. Thank you very much!

Comment: When you call `charAt()`, you're not changing anything - you're just obtaining a character. If you don't do anything to that character (e.g. store it in a variable or pass it to another function) the method does literally nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't post the entire code, it isn't exactly clear what you are trying to achieve. But this something that might help

```
public class StackOverflow {

public StackOverflow(){

}
public static void main( String[] args ){

    for( int x = 0, len = ((String)args[0]).length(); x < len; x++ )
            {
                char letter = args[0].charAt(x);

                switch (letter) 
                    {
                        case 'a': System.out.println("Z"); break;  //1

                        case 'e': System.out.println("Y"); break;  //2

                        case 'i': System.out.println("X"); break;     //3

                        case 'o': System.out.println("W"); break;  //4

                        case 'u': System.out.println("V"); break;  //5 

                        case 'A': System.out.println("z"); break;     //6

                        case 'E': System.out.println("y"); break;     //7

                    }
                }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "aei";
        for( int a = 0; a < str.length(); a++ )
        {
            char letter = str.charAt(a);
            switch (letter) 
                {
                    case 'a': System.out.print("Z"); break;  //1

                    case 'e': System.out.print("Y"); break;  //2

                    case 'i': System.out.print("X"); break;     //3

                    case 'o': System.out.print("W"); break;  //4

                    case 'u': System.out.print("V"); break;  //5 

                    case 'A': System.out.print("z"); break;     //6

                    case 'E': System.out.print("y"); break;     //7

                }
            }
```

Try this. Good Luck